# CMS similar to Umbraco but in PHP?

Tags: .net, php, umbraco

Is there a PHP CMS that works the same way as the .NET CMS Umbraco?

Ie. All data output comes as XML and is transformed with xslt. And you as a developer have more or less total freedom to create any structure and output as you wish.

Reason for asking: Working primarily on OS X / Mac and I'm not very experienced with .NET and the Microsoft web dev. environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML/XSLT pipeline haven't really been that popular in the PHP world for two reasons: 1) It is perceived as heavyweight, compared to using PHP or some other similar template language and 2) Because of PHPs stateless nature, the performance isn't too good (Or at least hard to get right).

Answer (score 3):

Umbraco really is very good and you don't need to know .net, that's the beauty, just some xslt.
It is even developed on a mac platform (admittedly in Fusion).

But I understand you wanting to stick with your strengths, so try symphony cms
http://symphony-cms.com/

Jay

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Joomla as a PHP CMS solution? It is as popular or possibly more popular that Umbraco with the "non-.Net" world...

Just a thought, I really don't know much about it at the point, but I am looking into it for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Modx (http://modx.com/). I'd argue that it is the most like Umbraco.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at other technologies (eg Java) which run on a Mac? If so you could look at Alfresco? Otherwise you can run Umbraco in a Windows VM such as VirtualBox (free) or Fusion

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at Alfresco. haven't really looked at anything besides PHP. Reason is, I'm most familiar with PHP but really like the Umbraco work..

Answer (score 0):

Check out EZPublish.. i dont think it uses xml/xslt, but allows full control of content etc, like Umbraco does.